# AngularJS Service Jasmine Unit Test Unflushed Request Error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, gulp, karma-jasmine

I'm writing my first unit test to check the functionality of a AngularJS service. This is the part of the service with the `getList` function I'm testing:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.services')
    .factory('RestService', RestService);

    RestService.$inject = [ '$http' ];

    function RestService($http) { 

        var service = {
            getList: getList,
            ...
        };
        return service;

        function getList(url) {
            return $http.get(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('RestService: got list: ' + response.data.length);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(errResponse) {
                console.error('RestService: error getting list: ' + errResponse.status);       
            });
        }
```

And I've written the following unit test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Test Rest Service', function() {

var httpBackend;
var RestService;
var reqHandler;

beforeEach(module('app.services'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, _RestService_) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    RestService = _RestService_;
    reqHandler = httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/events')
                    .respond(200, '[{ "event": 1 }, { "event": 2 }]');
}));

afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it('should get a list of events', function() {

    var url = '/api/events';
    httpBackend.expectGET(url);
    RestService.getList(url).then(function(response) {
        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(response.length).toEqual(2);
    });
});
});
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
Test Rest Service
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Test Rest Service "after each" hook FAILED
    Error: Unflushed requests: 1
```

My first guess is that then `then` part of the test is not executing but I can't find a way to check this. Can anyone explain why I have an unflushed request? Also, is there some way I can step through the test or at least print the variables to screen so I can figure out what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that `$scope.$digest()` flushes promises, so I would try: `var res = RestService.getList(url); $scope.$digest(); res.then(...);`. This way you can console.log the `res` as well and see if that works.

Comment: I'd tried your suggestion but I'll still getting the same error. I injected the scope in the `beforeEach` like so `var root = $injector.get('$rootScope'); scope = root.$new();` and then changed the test `var res = RestService.getList(url); scope.$digest(); res.then(function() { httpBackend.flush(); expect(res.length).toEqual(2); });`. Wish I could print to console where the code is executing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

httpBackend.flush is function, which causes return data from httpBackend. 
You can not call it in then block, because then is called when data are received (in this case never).

Right test code is

```
it('should get a list of events', function() {

  var url = '/api/events';
  httpBackend.expectGET(url);
  RestService.getList(url).then(function(response) {
    expect(response.length).toEqual(2);
  });

  httpBackend.flush();

});
```

working example - http://plnkr.co/edit/TA1HdQJaZHuShJiIIw6V?p=preview